# How does go implement Generic in built-in type like map and slice?

Tags: go

As we know, we can declare all type of map and slice,like `[]string, []int, []interface{}`
This is already some kind of Generic.

I wonder how it implements?
Is it just like `interface{}`, storing `type` and `value`, like using `void*` to implement Generic in c language?

Comment: i guess that there is some machinery generated by the compiler. For maps, for example, you can see that `mapaccess` receives a set of very special arguments and output an unsafe.Pointer https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.16.7:src/runtime/map.go;l=554;bpv=0;bpt=1

Comment: The type-modifier "slice" (note that slice by itself is not a type, it's always "slice of T" for some type T, which is why it is a "modifier") is handled *inside the compiler*. The compiler sees `[]T` as the type and inserts the appropriate necessary function calls, when function calls are necessary, or inline code, when inline code is appropriate. This is the same as handling `int` vs `uint64` vs `float32` directly in the compiler: we make sure we generate the correct code. That's all there really is in terms of the *language*.

Comment: In terms of the *implementation*, things get more interesting: to avoid writing multiple different map-accessors, slice-builders, and so on, we want the runtime system to be able to access information that the compiler leaves behind for the runtime system. So the runtime system itself is tied—weakly or strongly, depending on how much we want to tie it like this—to the compiler itself. In "mature" languages like C++, we tend to find that CPU manufacturers define ABIs so that the C++ compiler can call Intel's provided libraries, for instance.

Comment: In rapidly-advancing languages, like Go has been for some years, ABIs tend to be less common and the runtime is usually more closely tied to the specific compiler version. That makes it easier to provide a new faster compiler (faster to compile, or faster to run, whichever is more desirable) even if it means that you cannot use the new compiler with existing compiled object code.

Comment: The Go build system itself encourages a "whole source accessible at all times" model of compilation, which further avoids the kind of ossification that C++ ABIs tend to produce. There are pluses and minuses to every approach, though.

Answer (score 1):

Found related explanation in `Gopher Academy` youtube channel, Keith Randall explaining about maps and how it is implemented to have many types without generics.

video link - [Keith Randall - Inside the Map Implementation](https://youtu.be/Tl7mi9QmLns?t=767)

As it is described and you can see in [src/runtime/type.go](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.16.7:src/runtime/type.go;drc=refs%2Ftags%2Fgo1.16.7;l=31) Type informations are handled by this `_type`.

```
type _type struct {
    size       uintptr
    ptrdata    uintptr // size of memory prefix holding all pointers
    hash       uint32
    tflag      tflag
    align      uint8
    fieldAlign uint8
    kind       uint8
    // function for comparing objects of this type
    // (ptr to object A, ptr to object B) -> ==?
    equal func(unsafe.Pointer, unsafe.Pointer) bool
    // gcdata stores the GC type data for the garbage collector.
    // If the KindGCProg bit is set in kind, gcdata is a GC program.
    // Otherwise it is a ptrmask bitmap. See mbitmap.go for details.
    gcdata    *byte
    str       nameOff
    ptrToThis typeOff
}
```

`*_type` is using to describe key and element types in go maps, slices, arrays, channels.

ref := [maptype](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.16.7:src/runtime/type.go;drc=refs%2Ftags%2Fgo1.16.7;l=372), [slicetype](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.16.7:src/runtime/type.go;drc=refs%2Ftags%2Fgo1.16.7;l=416)

Comment: nice answer, thx! So it is still some kind of runtime generic, storing value and type like in c, not a build-time generic like template in c++.